# Electrical requirements for 3ph IR lamps

Tags: electrical

I have a series of lights that I want to use, with one controller, but do not know the electrical requirements.  the 15 total lamps, each lamps (IR) is 9000 watts, 27 amps, 240 3ph volts.  How do I calculate it?

Comment: A lamp cannot be 3-phase. A series of lamps or elements can. Please give us more information about this unit(s) and lamps. What specifically does it say on each lamp? What is the controller you are looking to use? Where are you located? Right now there is not nearly enough information to give an accurate answer.

Comment: In the US, residential service is not three phase.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should have a safety factor of 50%, so 9000 x15 x1.5 = 202,500 watts

This may be a bit high, as 27 x 240 is only 6480 watts (P = IxE)

Medical marijuana? Runway lighting? Rose bowl lighting?

This doesn't seem like a home application...  expect to defend WHY you need this or the question may get put on hold

Comment: "expect to defend WHY you need this or you'll get suspended"......Seriously? Is this in the rules somewhere?

Comment: Not user suspended..  the question..  I'll rephrase